# How to get the name of elements/attributes in xml files and write these into another new xml file using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, attributes

I am new to c#. Right now I am trying to get the name of some specific elements in an xml file and create a new xml file for these.
I have tried with LINQ, so that I can parse the xml and get the name of some elments that I want.
I do not want to use console.writeline to output this name. Instead I would like to create a new xml file and save these names in it.
Can anyone give me some tips?
The following is example data I would like to parse:

```xml
<root>
    <Package>
        <Class name="EnterpriseArchitect">
            <Operation/>
        </Class>
        <Class name="ZachmanFramework">
            <Operation/>
        </Class>
    </Package>
</root>
```

I want to get the attribute name of the element Class and save it in a new xml file like this:

```xml
<root>
<EnterpriseArchitect/>
<ZachmanFramework/>
</root>
```

The following is my c# code, but I can not reach the goal:

```cs
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\jsc\Desktop\123456.xml");
XDocument xNew = new XDocument();
var datatype = xdoc.Root.Elements("Package").Elements("Class")
            
foreach (var dut in datatype)
{
    var dataTypeName = dut.Attribute("name").Value;
    xNew.Add(new XElement(dataTypeName));
}
            
xNew.Save(@"C:\Users\jsc\Desktop\1234567.xml");
```

Comment: Please, read this: [XML Elements](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp) - section: **Naming Rules**. A name of xml node/element cannot contain spaces. So, `Enterprise Architect` won't be valid name.

Comment: sorry, i am new in xml. I will edit it right now

Comment: Also, new xml file have to have single root element...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, read my comments to the question.

This should work:

```
XDocument srcdoc = XDocument.Load("sourceFileName.xml");
List<XElement> names = srcdoc.Descendants("Class")
    .Select(x=> new XElement(x.Attribute("name").Value))
    //.Distinct() //uncomment this if duplicate values aren't allowed
    .ToList();

XDocument newdoc = new XDocument();
XElement root = new XElement("root");
root.Add(names);
newdoc.Add(root);   
newdoc.Save("newFileName.xml");
```

Good luck!

Comment: @S3152148, you're very welcome. The best way to say "Thanks" is to accept an answer (and upvote it). ;)